# Making a list inside an array of struct through functions

Tags: c, arrays, list

I'm trying to create an array of struct ,where each box contains the head of a list .Initially I make the array and then I need to use functions in order to make nodes for the list . 
The problem I'm dealing with has to do with the function as it does not work .
I'm note sure what I'm doing wrong...
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
   char user[50];
   char password[50];
   struct Photo *photohead;
}User; 

typedef struct
{
   int id;
   char des[50];
   char name[50];
   char place[50];
   char date[50];
   struct photo *next;
   struct Photo *prev;
}Photo;

User *CreateArray();
User *CreateArray(int size)
{
   int i;
   User *Userlist;
   FILE *fp;
   fp=fopen("clients.txt","r");
   if(fp==NULL){printf("failed to open file");}
   Userlist=malloc(size*sizeof(User));
   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
      fscanf(fp,"%s %s",Userlist[i].user,Userlist[i].password);
      Userlist[i].photohead=(Photo*)malloc(sizeof(Photo));
      Userlist[i].photohead=NULL;
   }

   fclose(fp);
   return Userlist;
};

void option1(Photo **head,char name[50],char date[50],
             char description[50],char location[50])
{

   Photo *temp;
   temp=(Photo*)malloc(sizeof(Photo));
   temp=head;
   while(temp->next!=NULL)
   {
      temp=temp->next;
   }

   temp->next=(Photo*)malloc(sizeof(Photo));
   strcpy(temp->next->name,name);
   strcpy(temp->next->date,date);
   strcpy(temp->next->des,description);
   strcpy(temp->next->place,location);

}

int main()
{
   char name[50],date[50],description[50],location[50];
   int option,user,sizze;
   User *Users;
   sizze=sizeofArray();//gets the size that the array needs to be from the file 
   Users=CreateArray(sizze)
      PrintArray(Users,sizze);

   printf("Enter the photos details\n");
   printf("Photos name:");
   scanf("%s",&name);
   printf("\n");
   printf("Photos date:");
   scanf("%s",&date);
   printf("\n");
   printf("Photos description:");
   scanf("%s",&description);
   printf("\n");
   printf("Photos location:");
   scanf("%s",&location);
   printf("\n");
   option1(&Users[user].photohead,name,date,description,location);
}
```

Comment: ...you set photohead twice...

Comment: Please indent your code with 4 spaces to make it readable.

Comment: The code does not compile. missing `;` after `CreateArray(sizze)`

Comment: Even after couple of fixes, the posted code has a lot of compiler warnings and errors. See http://ideone.com/rOox87.

Comment: * The problem I'm dealing with has to do with the function as it does not work . I'm note sure what I'm doing wrong*.  Our problem is we don't know what you mean exactly by *does not work*.  Your program does not compile and definitely requires some work to be useful, but you do not say what you expect and what you get.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misspellings and the poor coding , its my first time using stack overflow .

Comment: I'm expecting from the function to create new nodes at the end of the list for specific users .For example if Users[2] wants to add a new photo to his list I use the function in order to pass the pointer into the struct and create a new photo , in the end I can use that list inside main in order to display it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant, instead of this:

```
Userlist[i].photohead=(Photo*)malloc(sizeof(Photo));
Userlist[i].photohead=NULL;
```

this:

```
Userlist[i].photohead=(Photo*)malloc(sizeof(Photo));
Userlist[i].photohead.next=NULL;
```

This however may not completely solve your problem. No matter what, take a pencil and a piece of paper and draw how your list behaves, by executing your code by hand, taking into account three cases:

1. First node
2. Middle node
3. Last node

Answer (score 2):

`struct Photo` and `struct photo` are both undefined.

The `typedef struct { ... } Photo;` should read `typedef struct Photo { ... } Photo;`, and fix the spelling in `struct photo *next;`

Comment: Good answer, I was about to say that about the typo, but you got me, so +1!